# Typescript - Union Type of base interface and extended interface

Tags: typescript

I have the following code

```
interface BaseA {
  a: number;
}

interface SpecialA extends BaseA {
  b: number;
}

type A = BaseA | SpecialA

const a = {
    a: 5, b: 5
} as A

console.log(a.b)
```

I expected the code to be valid, but im getting the error

```
Property 'b' does not exist on type 'A'.
  Property 'b' does not exist on type 'BaseA'
```

It seems the type A is not what i was trying to define, i was expecting it to be equivelent to the following type

```
interface A {
  a: number;
  b?: number;
}
```

My questions are

1. why is the type A i defined different from the type A i expected to get?
2. how can i define the expected type A without defining it by hand?

Note: i need to use the type SpecialA as is in some places, so not defining it and just defining expected A is not an option.

Comment: @MikeS. Note that SpecialA also has the a property ( because it extends A ). regarding the b property im aware it might not exist on A, but why cant i even test for its existence to understand if the A object is a SpecialA object?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that later :) I guess i didn't see the `extends BaseA` part.. Silly me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `A` is a union, you need to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html)/[discriminate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) your type to access non shared members.

```
interface BaseA {
  a: number;
}

interface SpecialA extends BaseA {
  b: number;
}

type A = BaseA | SpecialA

const a = {
  a: 5, b: 5
} as A

if ("b" in a) { // narrowing here
  console.log(a.b)
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QILIN4CwAUMsnAFzIgCuAtgEbQDcxAvscaJLIigMoAHCAmBwANrggAPSCAAmGNJhz5ipepRoNmbDkTABPIclwBeJVlwAfZIOGiJehAHsQGMGWTnCJMpQCsADTIGsj%20bGSK2HrAMMgAFABE9InIoGQAlKq%20Lm7OYhAAdGLOAObxcIX0GWxAA)

Comment: Any idea why [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QILIN4CwAUMsnAFzIgCuAtgEbQDcxAvscaJLIigMoAHCAmBwANrggAPSCAAmGNJhz5ipepRoNmbDkTABPIclwBeJVlwAfZIOGiJehAHsQGMGUq5k5wiVIUyACMADRq6pQAzGwsRMQubs5iEAB0Ys4A5gAUcCn0AJSxxEA) works without problems, while `as A` does not?

Comment: @MikeS.  Since `a` is defined by a literal, the compiler infers `a` as `Special A`. It doesn't work if you reassign it  [See](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QILIN4CwAUMsnAFzIgCuAtgEbQDcxAvscaJLIigMoAHCAmBwANrggAPSCAAmGNJhz5ipepRoNmbDkTABPIclwBeJVlwAfZIOGiJesRDBlKuZOcIlSFZAEYAGjV1SgBmNhYiYjhPfD9-ViZkAHoU5CgITAxgAHMQUFy1YgQAexAMUucAOjFS3IAKOGr6AEpktKpS1wB3UqgAa0KgA)

Comment: Interesting, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

By using `as A`, you've said "The variable `a` may contain a `BaseA` or a `SpecialA`." Later, you tried to use `a.b` without any kind of type check, but since `a` may be just a `BaseA` (not a `SpecialA`), that's a type error. TypeScript doesn't **know** that what `a` refers to has a `b` property; it may be just a `BaseA`, which doesn't have `b`.

You can resolve that by checking first:

```
if ("b" in a) {
    console.log(a.b);
}
```

Within the `if` block, TypeScript knows that `a` refers to `SpecialA`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QILIN4BQyxycAXMiAK4C2ARtANwEC+BBoksiKAygA4QEwOABtcEAB6QQAEwxpMOfERJ0K1ek1bswAT0HJcAXkVZcAH2QChI8cwIIA9iAxhSyU4RKkKAVgAaVWJ1ZEDWUgVsB2AYZAAKACI6RORQUgBKFR9nVydRCAA6UScAc3i4QroM5hYgA)

You might be thinking: But `a` is a constant, not a variable. That's true, but the object the constant refers to can be modified to no longer have a `b` property:

```
delete (a as any).b; // blech
```

If you're never going to remove the `b` property, either just use `SpecialA` as the type:

```typescript
const a: SpecialA = {
    a: 5,
    b: 5,
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QILIN4BQyxycAXMiAK4C2ARtANwEC+BBoksiKAygA4QEwOABtcEAB6QQAEwxpMOfERJ0K1ek1bswAT0HJcAXkVZcAH2QChI8cwIIA9iAxhSFG8LEmVJD8gArAA0qsTqQaEsDs6uTqIQAHSiTgDmABRwiXQAlMxAA)

...or use `as const` to tell TypeScript that the object will never be modified:

```typescript
const a = {
    a: 5,
    b: 5,
} as const;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QILIN4BQyxycAXMiAK4C2ARtANwEC+BBoksiKAygA4QEwOABtcEAB6QQAEwxpMOfERJ0K1ek1bswAT0HJcAXkVZcAH2QChI8cwIIA9iAxhSyU4RKkKAVgAaVWJ1ZEDWUgVnVzAHaIwnUQgAOlEnAHMACjhkugBKZiA)

Note that if you do the `as const` thing, there's no need for a type annotation on it at all. TypeScript's type checking is structural (based on the shape of things, what properties they have and their types), not nominal (based on the names of types). But you could use the type `A` on it for some clarity for other programmers:

```typescript
const a: A = {
//     ^^^
    a: 5,
    b: 5,
} as const;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QILIN4BQyxycAXMiAK4C2ARtANwEC+BBoksiKAygA4QEwOABtcEAB6QQAEwxpMOfERJ0K1ek1bswAT0HJcAXkVZcAH2QChI8cwIIA9iAxhSFEypIfkAVgAaVWJ1fyCWUgVnVzAHaIwnUQgAOlEnAHMACjhkugBKZiA)